# jQuery ajax select input using button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using ajax to make a call and then PHP formats text and spits the generated HTML on the page and jQuery appends it to the body. This works fine.

In the generated code I have a button called ".update-info" in the element appended that when clicked, gets the fields above it and puts it into an object array (like submitting a form, but without leaving the page) which will be submitted via AJAX

```
$('.customer-info-container').on('click','.customer-info .update-info',function(event){
        search_path = $('.search-rel-path').val()+'insert/insert_new_customer';
        var textinput = {};
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children('input:text').each(function(e){
            if($(this).length > 0){
                textinput[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val(); 
            } 
        }); 
});
```

I'd dump the HTML in here to show you but basically the parent tree goes to the top of a table with 2 columns

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Label goes here</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="foo"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan=2>
    <button class="update-info">Update info</button>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

note: this is not to exact. There are something like 21 fields.

A console dump of textinput returns "undefined" so I'm doing something wrong. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any reason why you are not giving a name to your input?

Comment: You should use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)instead of multiple .parent()

Comment: I would have used that but can I still use the .each with closest?

Also all the inputs are named, I just didn't do it on here for the sake of fewer typed characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this part:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().children('input:text').each(...);
```

with:

```
$(this).closest("table").find('input:text').each(...);
```

you can also use jQuery `parents` function, like this:

```
$(this).parents("table")
```

the difference is, if you use `closest` it starts going up thru your DOM until it finds the first matched parent, but `parents` would result all matched ancestors in your DOM.

Comment: nah, you're good. I just didn't think to use .closest because I was thinking it's like... closest DOM element limiting it to one element.